# How to change a dropdown value based off of another dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have some JSON objects that I am populating into the first dropdown for a material number. Some of these material numbers have more than one location. I want to be able to select a material number from the first drop down and then the second dropdown to populate the locations for the material number. For example when I select 905-830005 in the first dropdown I need the options PROD and STERILE-PK to show in the second dropdown.

JSON: //Declared as RfqData in JQUERY below

```
[
 {"material":"900-100049","location":"STERILE-PK"},
 {"material":"900-100050","location":"STERILE-PK"},
 {"material":"900-110005","location":"PROD"},
 {"material":"900-600030","location":"STERILE-PK"},
 {"material":"900-600031","location":"STERILE-PK"},
 {"material":"905-830005","location":"PROD"},
 {"material":"905-830005","location":"STERILE-PK"},
 {"material":"905-830006","location":"PROD"},
 {"material":"905-830006","location":"STERILE-PK"},
 {"material":"905-860008","location":"STERILE-PK"},
 {"material":"905-860009","location":"STERILE-PK"}
]
```

HTML:

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td>Select Material:</td>
        <td><select id="selectMaterial" ><option></option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Location ID</td>
        <td ><select id="selectLocation"><option></option></select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQUERY:  //RfqData is my JSON string above

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var json = JSON.parse(SysGetElement('RfqData').value);  

        $.each(json, function () {
            $('#selectMaterial').append(
                $("<option></option>").text(this.material)
            );
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#selectMaterial').on('change',GetSelectLocation);
```

```
function GetSelectLocation() {

    //Here you get the selected materialId of your selectMaterial dropdown.
    var selectedMaterialId = $('#selectMaterial option:selected').val();

    //Now you must have your original list here. And using the above id fetch the list of location and create a location list. 
    var locationList = //fetch location list.
    $('#selectLocation').html("");
    $.each(locationList , function () {
    $('#selectLocation').append(
    $("<option></option>").text(this.location));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#selectMaterial").change( function(){
    var item = "";
    $("#selectLocation").empty();
    $.each(json, function () {
        if ($(this).val() == /*the material on json*/){
            item += '<option value="' + /*your value*/ + '">' + /*your value*/ + '</option>'
        }
    });
    $('#selectMaterial').html(item);
});
```

Comment: sorry this code isn't finished- I'll fill in the comments later